# How to configure SSL mongodb connection in YML file spring boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, ssl, jhipster

I was trying to setup a ssl mongodb connection from spring boot but I couldn't able to find a way to set a connection from `YML` file(beacuse it's easy to maintain dev and prod environment). How can I add client.PEM and rootCA.pem keys to below connection?

Please note this not a database administration question!

```
data:
     mongodb:
         authentication-database: admin
         database: <database>
         host: <host>
         password: <password>
         port: <port>
         username: <username>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve it is simple use URI string connect and database name in your application.yml file. Example:

```
data:  
    mongodb:  
      database: <databaseName>  
      uri: <mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]>
```

Example with SSL option:
mongodb://user:password@mongoServer:27017/?ssl=true

More info here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: OP also asked -> `How can I add client.PEM and rootCA.pem keys to below connection?`

Comment: Any hints on how to add client.PEM and rootCA.pem ???